# How to print the output on the console?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am trying to show the "curl's" output on the console when I execute it. Below is what I wrote. It prints the statement that I declared in `puts` for all the hostnames, which is as per designed.

```
 desc "check_app_version <environment> <project>", "checks the /dev/info page of the app"
       def check_app_version(environment, project)
         check_environment(environment)
         machines = `knife node list`.split
         machines.each do |hostname|
           puts "checking the app-version for #{hostname}"
           system("curl --silent -m 5 #{hostname}:8080/dev/info |grep 'Application\|Build'")
         end
       end
```

But I don't see anything for the next line which instructs to perform a curl on my servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the backtick notation to return a string, then return to `puts`

```
puts `curl --silent -m 5 #{hostname}:8080/dev/info |grep 'Application\|Build'`
```

Comment: i have refactored like this:   desc "check_app_version <environment> <project>", "checks the /dev/info page of the app"
       def check_app_version(environment, project)
         check_environment(environment)
         machines = `knife node list`.split
         machines.each do |hostname|
           puts "checking the app-version for #{hostname}"
           puts `curl --silent -m 5 #{hostname}:8080/dev/info |grep 'Application\|Build'`
         end
       end   But, the result show empty lines

Comment: for some reason, the space where the command puts `curl --silent -m 5 #{hostname}:8080/dev/info |grep 'Application\|Build'`  should print is left blank.

Comment: Remove the grep, try to rule out the possibility that grep is filtering everything out.

Comment: hey grep is the culprit. But the same curl with the grep works if executed manually.

Comment: You might have to double escape the backslash and/or pipe

Comment: how do i do that. I have tried some combinations, but it doesnt like it

Comment: Look up 'escaping and interpolating in ruby strings'

Answer (score 0):

```
puts `curl --silent -m 5 #{hostname}:8080/dev/info |grep 'Application\\|Build'`
```

Comment: care to explain how its different from already accepted answer?

Comment: @shivam - the last answer includes the escape for the 'back slash'. The final answer was posted to add the complete answer/solution to the original question.